# Element not known error in Karma when ran "ng test"

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

My project is running fine when i run

> ng serve

but it shows multiple errors when i run a simple "tobeTruthy()" test case using

> ng test

HTML FILE

```
<ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.8)" size="medium" color="#fff" type="ball-scale-multiple">
  <p style="font-size: 20px; color: white">Loading...</p>
</ngx-spinner>
<div *ngIf="isAuthenticated" class="container-fluid">
  <app-app-menu></app-app-menu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AppState } from './app.reducer';
import { UserState } from './core/store/core.state';
import * as CoreActions from './core/store/core.actions';
import { Globals } from './shared/globals';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  datetime = new Date();
  title = 'curemd-x';
  isAuthenticated = false;
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private router: Router,
    private globals: Globals) {}
...
   ...
```

Error in karma

```
 "Failed: Template parse errors:
'ngx-spinner' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-spinner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-spinner' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.8)" size="medium" color="#fff" type="ball-scale-multiple">
  <p"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@0:0
'app-app-menu' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-app-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-app-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
</ngx-spinner>
<div *ngIf="isAuthenticated" class="container-fluid">
  [ERROR ->]<app-app-menu></app-app-menu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@4:2
```

i also tried to include "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" but didn't work.

"app-app-menu" is a component present in core module and core module is imported in app.module

app.module.ts

```
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstOrDefaultPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    PatientModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(AppReducers),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    CoreModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DropDownsModule
  ],
  providers: [Globals],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

what can i do to run a successful test case for app module instance?

Comment: Could you try to run `npm run prod-build-staging --verbose`. Maybe this will give you more detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular developers often get confused by this. When you run `ng test`, karma and jasmine runs angular modules defined within `.spec.ts` files. It does not look at your normal code at all. So whatever you put in `app.module.ts` has no effect whatsoever on your test module. There are two things you could do.

1. Add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to testing module

   Within `app.component.spec.ts` do the following

```
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
   }).compileComponents();
```

This would solve the error you are getting now. However, you'll probably encounter others as I've seen you inject some services to `AppComponent` which brings us to next thing you could do

2. Import `AppModule` within test module.

   You could just import `AppModule` within `TestBed` as follows. What this will do is to ensure that your tests always have what they need defined. If you add another component to `AppModule` and use it in `AppComponent`, it will be already available in test as well. Also, you won't need to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`.

   However, you should be aware that this will import and create whatever 3rd party component/services you use within `app.component`. One would argue that it is against the nature of unit testing. You can still mock those services somehow but they will be rendered. Also, in angular applications, when testing a module that imports `RouterModule`, `RouterTestingModule` is used instead. Using `RouterModule` within test may mess your tests up as these tests run on a headless browser and `RouterModule` may cause URL changes.

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
```

Comment: Great! But if i don't wanna import the whole appModule and i have to import,declare and provide multiple packages or services to make it work, i can simply add it in my spec.ts file as i will add in module.ts ?

Comment: Also if i add few extra things in spec.ts that were not in module.ts will they effect my project size or compile time when i run "ng serve"? i assume it will obviously effect when i run "ng test"

Comment: Whatever you do in `spec` files does not affect your app at all. Also, yes you can import whatever you want in your `spec` file. If you don't want to import `AppModule` itself, I suggest you mock the services and components instead of importing the actual modules.

Answer (score 2):

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966708/1469932) is correct, meaning that it effectively solves the problem, please note the following:

- using `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` or `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` may result in "error swallowing". As explained in the [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#use-both-techniques-together), do not over-use them.
- importing `AppModule` means that you are writing an integration test. Usually, **it would be preferable to write an isolated unit test**.

Hence IMHO the best solution is to stub the unneeded components, as mentioned in the [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#stubbing-unneeded-components). Basically you will create an empty component with the same selector. While this may be tedious if you have a lot of components, I believe it is currently the best practice.