# Angular Karma testing errors of all components

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

My application load without any problems, but when I try ng test or npm test I have many errors of all components. First of all, I had problem with with app.e2e-2pec.ts with this line of code
  `expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('frontend app is running!');`
Error was:

```
ERROR in e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:16:41 - error TS2345: Argument of type '"frontend app is running!"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<string>>'.
```

Solution for this:

`expect<any>(.....)`

After this, I faced bunch off errors in whole test environment under Karma. Just some of them

```
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) ApiService should be created FAILED
        NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]: 
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: 
            NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ Function ] })
            at <Jasmine>
            at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:855:1)
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
            at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30393:1)
            at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31578:1)
            at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:734:1)
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 9 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.039 secs)
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) ApiService should be created FAILED
        NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]: 
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: 
            NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ Function ] })
            at <Jasmine>
            at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:855:1)
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
            at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30393:1)
            at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31578:1)
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) NotesServiceService should be created FAILED
        NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]: 
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: 
            NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ Function ] })
            at <Jasmine>
            at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:855:1)
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
            at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30393:1)
            at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31578:1)
            at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:734:1)
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 5 of 9 (2 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.068 secs)
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) NotesServiceService should be created FAILED
        NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]: 
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: 
            NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ Function ] })
            at <Jasmine>
            at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:855:1)
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
            at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
            at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
            at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
            at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30393:1)
            at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31578:1)
```

```
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) AppComponent should render title FAILED
        Failed: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
        error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
        Error: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
            at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2175:1)
            at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20215:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20115:1
            at <Jasmine>
            at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20106:1)
            at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25824:1)
            at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25813:1)
            at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25775:1)
            at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.js:244:1)
            at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/testing.js:159:1)
        Error: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
        error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
            at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2175:1)
            at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20215:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20115:1
            at <Jasmine>
            at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20106:1)
            at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25824:1)
            at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25813:1)
            at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25772:1)
            at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.js:232:1)
            at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/testing.js:151:1)
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 7 of 9 (3 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.133 secs)
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) AppComponent should render title FAILED
        Failed: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
        error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
        Error: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
            at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2175:1)
            at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20215:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20115:1
            at <Jasmine>
            at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20106:1)
            at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25824:1)
            at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25813:1)
            at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25775:1)
            at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.js:244:1)
            at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/testing.js:159:1)
        Error: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
        error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
            at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2175:1)
            at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20215:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20115:1
            at <Jasmine>
            at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20106:1)
            at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25824:1)
            at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25813:1)
            at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25772:1)
            at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.js:232:1)
            at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynaChrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) AppComponent should have as title 'frontend' FAILED
```

```
   Failed: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
        error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
        Error: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
            at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2175:1)
            at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20215:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20115:1
            at <Jasmine>
            at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20106:1)
            at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25824:1)
            at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25813:1)
            at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25775:1)
            at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.js:244:1)
            at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/testing.js:159:1)
        Error: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
        error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
            at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2175:1)
            at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20215:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20115:1
            at <Jasmine>
            at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20106:1)
            at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25824:1)
            at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25813:1)
            at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25772:1)
            at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.js:232:1)
            at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/testing.js:151:1)
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 9 of 9 (5 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.181 secs)
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) AppComponent should create the app FAILED
        Failed: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
        error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
        Error: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
            at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2175:1)
            at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20215:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20115:1
            at <Jasmine>
            at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20106:1)
            at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25824:1)
            at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25813:1)
            at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25775:1)
            at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.js:244:1)
            at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/testing.js:159:1)
        Error: Type AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving AppComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AppComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and DynamicTestModule.
        error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
            at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2175:1)
            at CompileMetadataResolver._addTypeToModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20215:1)
            at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20115:1
            at <Jasmine>
            at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:20106:1)
            at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25824:1)
            at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25813:1)
            at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25772:1)
            at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.js:232:1)
            at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynaChrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 9 of 9 (5 FAILED) (0.443 secs / 0.181 secs)
TOTAL: 5 FAILED, 4 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 5 FAILED, 4 SUCCESS
```

After this errors I changed my TestBed in app.component.spec.ts and added

```
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

But it is also the same. I am trying to test angular app for the first time and I am a bit confused. Saw this question:
[Element not known error in Karma when ran "ng test"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55966510/element-not-known-error-in-karma-when-ran-ng-test)

Also my application is working fine, it is connecting with backend and all main functionality has been done. Any help would be very appreciated.

SOLVED:
Thanks guys for help, user Pace get me on track. When I was creating my components I always deleted spec.ts files, because I do need them to perform unit test for services and pipes filter, but one mistake has been made :). Ad the beginning of creating application using angular cli I did not delete app.component.spec.ts, so this errors have sense, because this component wanted to load all other components for testing purposes but could not find their test files. I am a big noob in Angular and get a bit scary when see this big errors, haha :))

Comment: Have these tests worked for you in the past?  Can you post the actual test files?  Hard to determine the problem just by errors.

Comment: I do not have any tests at the moment. Just finished my app and wanted to run ng test, just to see if Karma is working.

Comment: The default tests are setup to pass for the application that the CLI generates.  They will fail once you start adding dependencies.  You'll need to update the tests to include whatever dependencies you added to your app (i.e. HttpClient).

Comment: So when I have component, or service which contains .spec.ts file I need to add all dependencies like this for example. My service is injecting in constructor: ``` constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  } ``` , so in test ts file I can add in beforeEach imports:[HttpClientTestingModule] and providers: [ApiService]. Also I am a bit confused, because I was following a short course and it worked without any problems on video, maybe it is just because I got newer Angular version. Thanks for answer, will try to mess with it tomorrow.

Comment: When you generate an Angular app with the CLI I think you can tell it to skip generating tests.  Maybe the tutorial did that so they didn’t have all the .spec files.

Comment: Thanks Pace, this helped me. More information in post after edit.